# Copy row above the row containing certain text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to copy the entire row if column B contains a certain text ("ACK-", but now I need to copy the entire row directly above the one with the certain text ("ACK-". Is this even possible? Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub HEA_Filter()
Dim strArray As Variant
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim NoRows As Long
Dim DestNoRows As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Integer
Dim rngCells As Range
Dim rngFind As Range
Dim Found As Boolean

strArray = Array("ack-")

Set wsSource = ActiveSheet

NoRows = wsSource.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
DestNoRows = 1
Set wsDest = Sheets("Real Alarms")

For I = 1 To NoRows

Set rngCells = wsSource.Range("B" & I)
Found = False
For J = 0 To UBound(strArray)
Found = Found Or Not (rngCells.Find(strArray(J)) Is Nothing)
Next J

If Found Then
rngCells.EntireRow.Copy wsDest.Range("A" & DestNoRows)

DestNoRows = DestNoRows + 1
End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked great! thanks! Now I have another problem... When trying to change the paste column from "A" to "F" it gives me an error saying that the cell is not the same size... How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To reference *"the row above"*, you can use the `Range.Offset` method:

```
rngCells.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Copy wsDest.Range("A" & DestNoRows)
'       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, be aware that this raised a runtime error if the range is at row 1, because `row 0` does not exist. You might want to add a check for it, for example:

```
If rngCells.Row > 1 Then rngCells.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Copy ...
```

Comment: That worked great! thanks! Now I have another problem... When trying to change the paste column from "A" to "F" it gives me an error saying that the cell is not the same size...

Comment: @JimmyVo did you just use `wsDest.Range("A" & DestNoRows)`? If so, it shouldn't give you that error, unless you probably have some merged cells, or too many rows of data, idk.

Comment: To avoid the `If rngCells.Row > 1 Then`, the loop could be changed to be `For I = 2 To NoRows`.