# Copy/Paste data that is not the entre row

Tags: vba, excel

I cannot paste anywhere besides column "A" I have tried changing the column letter, but I get an error code saying the "copy/paste cell are not the same size".

```
Sub HEA_Filter_Names()

Dim strArray As Variant
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim NoRows As Long
Dim DestNoRows As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Integer
Dim rngCells As Range
Dim rngFind As Range
Dim Found As Boolean

strArray = Array("ack-")

Set wsSource = ActiveSheet

NoRows = wsSource.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
DestNoRows = 1
Set wsDest = Sheets("Real Alarms")

For I = 1 To NoRows

    Set rngCells = wsSource.Range("B" & I)
    Found = False

    For J = 0 To UBound(strArray)
        Found = Found Or Not (rngCells.Find(strArray(J)) Is Nothing)
    Next J

    If Found Then
        rngCells.EntireRow.Copy wsDest.Range("A" & DestNoRows)
        DestNoRows = DestNoRows + 1
    End If

Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are copying an entire row, the only place you will be able to paste it is somewhere where an entire row will fit - i.e. column A.  Perhaps you need to tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Of course it's going to paste to column A. What do you think the `A` in `wsDest.Range("A" & DestNoRows)` means? A row starts in column A, so if you're copying a row it **has** to start in column A.

Comment: @JimmyVo I didn't catch it in you other question. I see now. Hope all is solved and that you can start [accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: A row starts in column A. If you're copying a row, and all rows start in column A, where else would you expect it to start?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot paste an `EntireRow` starting anywhere else than column `A`.

You can try this instead:

```
Intersect(rngCells.EntireRow, rngCells.Parent.UsedRange).Copy wsDest.Range("F" & DestNoRows)
```

Comment: @YowE3K take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45395541/4926357)... Didn't notice the problem of entire row unless I saw the new question. Somehow I feel getting tired of the "no-ending question lists"... if you see what I mean.

Comment: You shouldn't ask me to look at your other answers - I then have to comment on them too :D

Comment: @YowE3K LOL, I will always do, precisely because I appreciate your comments :)

Comment: I just woke up, don't you guys ever sleep ? or you take naps on the keyboard from one post till the next ;)